# unable to get the output of ternary operator

Tags: c, ternary-operator

Code

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int big, x = 3, y = 2, z = 1, q = 4;

    big = (x > y
        ? (z > x ? 20 : 10 && x > y ? 85 : 12)
        : (y > z ? 40 : 10 || x < q ? 30 : 10)
    );

    printf("\nbig =%d", big);
    //getch();
}
```

Ouput is 85 But Iam not sure how it's working Help me to understand it..

Comment: Please don't nest ternary statements like that, it's practically unreadable. Your colleagues will thank you for writing it in multiple statements which can be easily visually parsed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&&` has higher precedence than `?:`.

```
big=(x>y?(z>x?20:10 && x>y?85:12): (y>z?40:10 || x<q?30:10));`
```

will be parsed as

```
big=(x>y?(z>x ? 20: ( (10 && x>y) ?85:12) ): (y>z ? 40: (10 || x<q?30:10)));
```

Since `x` is greater than `y`, so `20: (10 && x>y?85:12)` will be executed. Both `10` and `x > y` will be evaluated to `true`, `(10 && x>y) ?85:12)` will give `85`.